# FaunaDB: How to get documents created in the last hour?

Tags: faunadb

How to get all documents created in the last hour?

I found `Paginate()` parameter **ts**, but it only returns documents created earlier, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, this code:

```js
Paginate(Documents(Collection("fweets")), {
  events: true,
  after: Time("2020-05-22T19:12:07.121247Z")
})
```

should return the events after the given timestamp, do you encounter an issue trying to run such code?

The events from that result will include create **and** delete events. An alternative way is to create an index on 'ts' but this will also give you documents that were updated after the given timestamp.

```js
Paginate(
    Range(
      Match(Index("fweets_after_ts")),
      ToMicros(Time("2020-05-22T19:12:07.121247Z")),
      null
    )
  )
```

A popular approach is to get the events of these created/updated docs then by running Pagiante with events again on top of that result. Which you can do by wrapping it in a map + paginate with events: true.

```js
Map(Paginate(
    Range(
      Match(Index("fweets_after_ts")),
      ToMicros(Time("2020-05-22T19:12:07.121247Z")),
      null
    )
  ),
  Lambda(['ts', 'ref'], Paginate(Var('ref'), {events: true, after: Time("2020-05-22T19:12:07.121247Z")}))
)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Sorry, I'm so ahamed for such stupid question, but I started learn faunadb yesterday :-) 

My mistake was that I tried `TimeSubtract(Now(), 10, 'minutes')`, instead of `ToMicros(TimeSubtract(Now(), 10, 'minutes'))`

Comment: No problem :).There is an active community here in case you are searching for further help on how to get started: https://forums.fauna.com/